# Postgres connection refused when running laravel tests on gitlab CI

Tags: laravel, postgresql, gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

I am trying to get my test suite running on GitLab CI but I'm running into a connection refused problem. I have been trying for a while to diagnose and resolve this unfortunately to no avail.

I don't believe it is a docker networking issue, as the service should be exposed to the app's testing stage. I don't run database migrations as I'm only looking to run the test suite, which uses the `test` database.

(The testing database relies on the regular database credentials in my `config.php` file, so DB_HOST etc. will work for it, as it does locally + on GitHub Actions.)

I believe the issue is related to my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

The error:

> QueryException
> pest_tests      >   SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
> pest_tests      >       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
> pest_tests      >       TCP/IP connections on port 5432? (Connection: testing, SQL: select tablename, concat('"', schemaname, '"."', tablename, '"') as qualifiedname from pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname in ('public'))

My .gitlab.ci-yml file

```
stages:
  - preparation
  - building
  - testing
  #- deployment

default:
    image: thecodingmachine/php:8.2-v4-fpm-node18
    services:
      - postgres:latest
  
variables:
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_DB: test
    PHP_EXTENSIONS: intl pdo_pgsql pdo_sqlite gd

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/
    - node_modules/
    
composer:
  stage: preparation
  script:
    - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts
    - cp .env.ci .env
    - php artisan key:generate
    
npm:
  stage: preparation
  script:
    - npm install

build_assets:
  stage: building
  dependencies:
    - npm
  script:
    - npm run build   

pest_tests:
  stage: testing
  dependencies:
    - composer
    - npm
    - build_assets
  script:
    - php vendor/bin/pest     
    
static_analysis:
  stage: testing
  dependencies:
    - composer
  script:
    - php vendor/bin/phpstan analyse
       
code_style:
 stage: testing
 dependencies:
    - composer
    - npm
 script:
    - php vendor/bin/pint
```

The database section of my `.env.ci` file.

```
# -- Database --
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres

# -- Testing Database --
TESTING_DB_DATABASE=test
```

Here's the relevant section of my `database.php` file just so you've got the full picture. This is referenced in my `phpunit.xml` file.

```
        // This is the connection that we will use for testing.
        'testing' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('TESTING_DATABASE_URL') ?? env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('TESTING_DB_HOST') ?? env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('TESTING_DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('TESTING_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('TESTING_DB_USERNAME') ?? env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('TESTING_DB_PASSWORD') ?? env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'search_path' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
```

If you could help me out I'd appreciate it, I'm not very good at configuring this kind of stuff! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1"

You're trying to access the postgres service using localhost/`127.0.0.1`. However, the postgres container is available at the hostname `postgres`. You need to configure your application code under test to use this hostname when connecting to the database.

You mentioned you have `DB_HOST` set to `postgres` in your `.env.ci` file and your phpunit file seems to try to get this: `env('TESTING_DB_HOST') ?? env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1')` but something is wrong here because the error clearly shows 127.0.0.1 -- so it seems like your env variables aren't being set in some case.

In one job, you do the following:

```
    - cp .env.ci .env
```

But this line doesn't seem to be present in all your other jobs, including `pest_tests`. Perhaps this is what you're missing to ensure your variables are being set correctly for your tests.

Or perhaps you can add `TESTING_DB_HOST` and/or `DB_HOST` to your `variables:` section in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` to be defined as `postgres`. That should solve the issue, as far as I can tell, assuming your phpunit file is being used appropriately.